# Dynamic key / value form reactive angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I've searched for a long time and I didn't find what I want to do. I would like to add dynamic key/value with angular 5 and reactive form.

When I click on a button "add parameter", 2 inputs appear dynamically. One for key, the other for the value.

And when I submit my form, I would like to get this :

{ 
settings : {
   key1: value1,
   key2: value2...
}
}

Here what I've done :

my component :

```html
        constructor(
        protected fb: FormBuilder,

    ) {

        // form init
        this.testForm = fb.group({
            'name': fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
            'desc': fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
            'config': fb.array([])
        });
    }
    
    
    ...

getControls(frmGrp: FormGroup, key: string) {
    return (<FormArray>frmGrp.controls[key]).controls;
}
    
 
    addConfigBlock() {

        let settingBlock = this.testForm.get('setting') as FormArray;

        settingBlock.push(this.fb.group({key: '', value: ''}));


    }
```

template.html

```html
                <div fxLayout="column" fxflex="100%" class="form-standard">
                    <div formArrayName="config" *ngFor="let setting of getControls(testForm, 'config'); let i = index;">
                        <div [formGroupName]="i" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="100%"> 
                            <mat-form-field class="form-input"> 
                                <input matInput formControlName="key" name="key" maxlength="255"
                                placeholder="Key" required> 
                            </mat-form-field>
                            <mat-form-field class="form-input"> 
                                <input matInput formControlName="value" name="value" maxlength="255"
                                    placeholder="Value" required> 

                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <mat-card-content class="mat-card-content">
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch" class="form-standard">
                        <div fxFlex.gt-md="100" fxFlex.xs="100">
                            <div fxLayoutAlign="space-around stretch">
                                <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addSetting()">Add setting</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-card-content>
```

I don't know what is the best way to achieve this. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, is to make use of a variable in the component that keeps track of the index, on each add, increment the variable. Then use that value in the naming of the form control, so something like...

```ts
i = 0;

addConfigBlock() {
  let settingBlock = this.testForm.get('config') as FormArray;
  settingBlock.push(this.fb.group({['key'+this.i] : '', ['value'+this.i]: '' }));
  this.i++;
}
```

and in the template you mark the formcontrols with

```ts
formControlName="key{{i}}"
formControlName="value{{i}}"
```

where `i` is the index in your iteration.

Here's a

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3w7qbr?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have some error and I don't know why when I fill up the fields "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false".

Comment: Please reproduce the issue in the demo I made and I'd be happy to take a look :)

Comment: Thank you again for you help ! The StackBlitz you provide has this error. You click on the button, fill up the fields and click again on the button, you'll see the error appears into the console

Answer (score 0):

I was in a situation where I wanted to add a control dynamically but knew exactly which control I wanted to add. This scenario occurred because I wanted to save all control values in an array in the backend instead of listing them separately. Here's a solution to this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="myArray">
    <div [formGroup]="getControl('my_known_control_name')">
      <mat-checkbox formControlName="value">My known control name</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div [formGroup]="getControl('my_second_known_control_name')">
      <mat-checkbox formControlName="value">My second known control name</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
// reactive device form
myForm!: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  myArray: this.fb.array([]),
});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

getControl(field: string): FormGroup {
  var myArray = this.myForm.get('myArray') as FormArray | null;
  var existingControl = myArray?.controls.find(c => c.value["name"] === field);
  if (existingControl) {
    return existingControl as FormGroup;
  } else {
    var newControl = this.fb.group({
      name: field,
      value: undefined,
    });
    myArray?.push(newControl);
    return newControl;
  }
}
```